# JSF Error page not shown when ViewExpiredException occurs

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, exception, primefaces, omnifaces

I have the following error when *view* within a page is expired. The message says that the `Error page '/home.xhtml' will be shown.` but actually nothing is shown, the page remains the same, and it is just frozen. I am using *FullAjaxExceptionHandler* from *Omnifaces*, described by [balusC](http://balusc.blogspot.co.at/2012/03/full-ajax-exception-handler.html).

I am using Primefaces 3.5 and Mojarra 2.1.17.

```
Mär 11, 2013 1:40:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: FullAjaxExceptionHandlerx: An exception occurred during processing JSF ajax request. Error page '/home.xhtml' will be shown.
javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId:/wishes_book.xhtml - View /wishes_book.xhtml could not be restored.
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:205)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1812)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Mär 11, 2013 1:40:30 PM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/home.xhtml]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.getWidgetBuilder(CoreRenderer.java:481)
    at org.primefaces.component.menubar.MenubarRenderer.encodeScript(MenubarRenderer.java:36)
    at org.primefaces.component.menu.BaseMenuRenderer.encodeEnd(BaseMenuRenderer.java:40)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeRow(PanelGridRenderer.java:143)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeStaticBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:107)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:63)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelGridRenderer.java:49)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeRow(PanelGridRenderer.java:143)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeStaticBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:107)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:63)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelGridRenderer.java:49)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.renderAll(PartialViewContextImpl.java:404)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:289)
    at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:183)
    at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:183)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:982)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:411)
    at com.meinanliegen.handlers.exceptions.FullAjaxExceptionHandler.renderErrorPageView(FullAjaxExceptionHandler.java:231)
    at com.meinanliegen.handlers.exceptions.FullAjaxExceptionHandler.handleAjaxException(FullAjaxExceptionHandler.java:200)
    at com.meinanliegen.handlers.exceptions.FullAjaxExceptionHandler.handle(FullAjaxExceptionHandler.java:145)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1812)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Mär 11, 2013 1:40:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/MeinAnliegen] threw exception
```

Can  you please help me with one suggestion how could I solve his problem?

Comment: Are you shore that your `home.xhtml` file is on right location?

Comment: Is this the full stack trace?

Comment: This is caused by PrimeFaces 3.5. You need to update OmniFaces to at least 1.4 (it's currently 1.4.1). See also https://code.google.com/p/omnifaces/issues/detail?id=120

Comment: @BalusC : Thanks, this was indeed the solution. Can you write an answer so I can mark it as accepted? And again many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by PrimeFaces 3.5. They added a `PhaseListener` which creates and puts a `WidgetBuilder` as context attribute during render response phase. The `FullAjaxExceptionHandler` however forces rendering directly in the current phase when not in render response phase yet. This caused the `WidgetBuilder` to be `null` during encoding of PrimeFaces components and hence this NPE. Also, when the current phase is render response, then it would still not work because `FullAjaxExceptionHandler` was a bit too agressively clearing the entire context attribute map before rendering (with the sole reason to force re-injection of JSF resource dependencies like CSS/JS files), including the PrimeFaces `WidgetBuilder`.

This is reported as [OmniFaces issue 120](http://code.google.com/p/omnifaces/issues/detail?id=120). The `FullAjaxExceptionHandler` was improved to delegate the rendering to JSF when currently not in render response phase, and remove only the specific attributes from the context attribute map. You need to update OmniFaces to at least 1.4 (it's currently 1.4.1) in order to get it to work.